# React cannot render array of elements from api

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, reactjs

When i try to map over this:

```
 //api [{"id":1,"label":"Testing","items":[{"id":1,"value":"Learn React","flag":2},{"id":2,"value":"Learn .net","flag":2}]},{"id":2,"label":"Testing","items":[{"id":1,"value":"Learn React","flag":2},{"id":2,"value":"Learn .net","flag":2}]}]

 renderLists() {
        const lists =this.props.data.map((item, index) => <Holder data={item} key={index} />);
        console.log(this.props.data);
        return (
            { lists }
        ); 
    }
```

function i get an error:

> Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {lists}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

Comment: Add code in the question

Comment: How does your `props.data` look like?

Comment: Use `this.props.data.items.map()`

Comment: What does `<Holder />` look like?

Comment: Wrapping it solved the  problem :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try wrapping it? e.g.:

```
const lists = this.props.data.map((item, index) => <Holder data={item} key={index} />);
console.log(this.props.data);
return (
    <React.Fragment>
      { lists }
    </React.Fragment>
);
```